Turbine awaitItem() not fetching correct StateFlow value
I have a ViewModel with the following code (simplified for better understanding):
@HiltViewModel
class OptionsGameViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val fetchOptionsUseCase: fetchOptionsUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _gameState = MutableStateFlow(GameState()) // GameState() starts with optionsSize = 1
    val gameState = _gameState.asStateFlow()

    fun init(bundle: Bundle?) {
        /* fetching info from Bundle */
        startGame()
    }

    private fun startGame() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            fetchOptionsUseCase(param1, param2).collect {
                _gameState.value = _gameState.value.copy(
                    roundState = _gameState.value.roundState.copy(optionsSize = it.size),
                )
                /* Other stuff unrelated to the test */
            }
        }
    }
}

Basically, when I init() my ViewModel, I start my game by first fetching the necessary info for the game. One of said infos is the size of the list that my fetchOptionsUseCase() returns. I'm trying to test exactly that, so I created this test:
class OptionsGameViewModelTest {
    private val bundle = mockk<Bundle>()
    private val fetchOptionsUseCase = mockk<fetchOptionsUseCase>()
    private val viewModel = OptionsGameViewModel(fetchOptionsUseCase)

    @Test
    fun onInit_withFourNumberOfOptions_assertGameStateOptionsSizeEqualsToFour() =
        runTest {
            prepareBundleMock() // the bundle itself is irrelevant for this unit test.
            val numberOfOptions = 4
            coEvery {
                fetchOptionsUseCase(any(), any())
            } returns flowOf(OptionsUiModelFactory.makeList(listSize = numberOfOptions))

            viewModel.gameState.test {
                viewModel.init(bundle)
                assertEquals(numberOfOptions, awaitItem().roundState.optionsSize)
            }
        }
}

However, I get the error:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <4> but was: <1>

Which honestly makes no sense to me since I'm already collecting gameState values by running my viewModel.init(bundle) inside of the .test { } block. At least that's what I understood from the docs.
I managed to make a test that works by using backgroundScope and calling viewModel.gameState.first(), but honestly I've no ideia why this works but Turbine's .test {} doesn't.
Here's the functional test:
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Test
fun onInit_withRandomNumberOfOptions_assertGameStateOptionsSizeEqualsToRandomNumber() =
    runTest {
        prepareBundleMock()
        val numberOfOptions = randomInt()
        coEvery {
            fetchOptionsUseCase(any(), any())
        } returns flowOf(OptionsUiModelFactory.makeList(listSize = numberOfOptions))

        backgroundScope.launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)) {
            viewModel.init(bundle)
            val gameState = viewModel.gameState.first()
            assertEquals(numberOfOptions, gameState.roundState.optionsSize)
        }
    }

How can I properly test my StateFlow using Turbine in this case?

Could you please provide the interface signature/definition of the FetchOptionsUseCase? From the test you have written it looks that is has suspend function returning Flow, which in most cases is wrong.
Regarding the test method itself, this line backgroundScope.launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)) looks unusual. Usually we provide dispatcher as an argument of the runTest {} builder. With the Turbine lib, you should be able to test of type of Flows, cold and hot.
I am happy to help with your case but please share the use case interface.
